# Filter row with one specific string value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filtering, stringr

I have a dataframe in R as below:

```
Fruits
Apple:1
Apple:4
Bananna    
Papaya    
Orange, Apple:2
```

I want to filter rows with string Apple as

```
Apple:1
Apple:4
```

I tried using dplyr package.

```
df <- dplyr::filter(df, grepl('Apple', Fruits))
```

But it filters rows with string Apple as:

```
Apple:1
Apple: 4     
Orange, Apple:2
```

How to remove rows with multiple strings and filter rows with one specific string (in this case Apple)?

Comment: Why don't you just use the `==` operator? `filter(df, Fruits == "Apple")`

Comment: @benson  I have modified the example output above. There are multiple entries of the specific string separated by colon and number. I want to exclude the rows where this string (apple) is with other strings (orange)

Comment: @Atom I see your point now, see if my solution works :)

Comment: Would you ever have an entry like `"Apple:2, Orange"`? or will the other word come first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

Assuming, based on comments made by OP, that strings should be filtered where **the only fruit mentioned** is `Apple` and assuming further that the list of non-`Apple` fruit is manageable, you could do this:

```
df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Fruits, '^(?!.*Banana|Orange).*Apple'))
                   Fruits
1 Apple, Apple:2, Apple:7
```

Here, we use negative look-ahead `(?!.*Banana|Orange)` to assert that `Banana` or `Orange` must not be present in the string together with `Apple`

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Fruits = c("Orange, Apple:2", 
             "Apple, Apple:2, Apple:7", 
             "Apple:2, Banana:10"))
```

Answer (score 2):

To only filter out `Apple`, you can use the regex anchor `^` to specify the start of a string, followed by "Apple:" and any digits. Finally close the search pattern with `$`, which specifies the end of a string, where the above pattern could happen more than once. The search will return `FALSE` if you have any other characters in between the string.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(grepl("^(Apple:\\d+(, )?){1,}$", Fruits))

   Fruits
1 Apple:1
2 Apple:4
```

Comment: Thank you. It filtered rows where Apple was given as first entry.  example:Apple:1, Orange was also selected. I want to filter rows with Apple given as entry as single like Apple:1 or multiple entries like Apple:2, Apple:4

Comment: @Atom See if my updated code works :)

Comment: Thank you, it worked on lines with single entry of the string, but did not find lines with multiple entries of the string